# SSIS Package is working fine in SSDT but throwing an error in a SQL Server Agent JOB

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting the error shown below using a SSIS package created in SSDT 2019 and SQL Server 2019 in SSMS v18.4.

It's working fine when I am running it from SSDT and only throwing the error when run in a SQL Server agent job. I am not passing any parameters. It's a simple package with just one script task. I don't think it's an issue with the script task because I also checked with execute process task in SSIS with simple different package and that is also throwing the same error.

Is there any help? Thanks in advance....

**Error:**

> Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Script Task", type "Microsoft.ScriptTask" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".  End Error  Error: 2019-12-23 00:29:35.22
>   Code: 0xC0010018
>   Source: Script Task
>
> Description: Failed to load task "Script Task", type "". The contact information for this task is "".  End Error  Error: 2019-12-23 00:29:35.22
>   Code: 0xC0010026
>   Source: Script Task
>
> Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".  End Error Error: 2019-12-23 00:29:35.22
>   Code: 0xC0024107
>   Source: Script Task
>
> Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error Error: 2019-12-23 00:29:35.22
>   Code: 0xC0010025
>   Source: Package2
>
> Description: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load. End Error
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started:  12:29:35 AM
>   Finished: 12:29:35 AM
>   Elapsed:  0.094 seconds.
>   The package execution failed. The step failed.

Comment: Where is the package deployed? Is the build code used to deploy?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?